# bitmap normalization in android for illumination solving

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap, normalization

i have developed an android app for color comparison. and i ve successfully completed the app except solving one problem that is illumination problem. my reference chart is in sdcard as jpeg images I need to compare those images with the images which i takes from camera. i am getting the output but it depends the illuminity. so now i am planing no normalize the bit maps. How to normalize a bitmap.?? i am comparing images using naive similarity method
and please suggest me one good idea to solve the illumination problem. searching metheds sonce last two weeks .

Comment: hey i asked this problem 4 or five times. nobody helping me. iam stuck at testing you gys.

Answer (score 0):

[here is a link asking a similar question about luminosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960408/light-measuring-in-andoid), so I won't repeat everything.

Color is perceptual, not an absolute. Take a red car and park it under a street light and the car will appear to be orange. Obviously the color of the paint has not changed, only your perception of the color has changed.

Any time you take a photo of color, the light used to illuminate the image will change the results you get. Most cameras have a light balance control, where most people use auto. The auto control looks something to call white, then shifts the image to make the white look white. This does not mean the rest of the colors will be correct.

Take something like a colorful stuffed animal (or a few) and take its photo outside in sunlight, under an incandescent bulb, under florescent light and in a dark room with the camera flash. How similar are the colors? If you have photoshop, look at the color curves in photoshop.

To match color, you need an [objective standard](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/vlue/vlue1101/vlue110100078/8573763-a-man-holds-up-an-18--gray-white-balance-card-with-test-colors-on-it-to-calibrate-the-colors-perfect.jpg), such as a color card included in the photo. Then the software brightness and color correct the known card, then measure the other color to the known standards.